# Trying to design an appropriate UI for holding 4,000 plus records

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, layout, data, social-interfaces

I'm new to UI design so basically I'm trying to make a simple application that displays the current population of a species and it's trend of going up or down from the previous year.

The trouble I'm running into is that because there's so many species I'm not sure how to organize the information where it can be easily searched through. There's not many columns but there can be possibly 4,000 or more species if I account for all of them. Is there a design that any of you could suggest which would help make this feasible.

Below I put the columns I was thinking of adding. Overall I just want to make it easy and friendly for people to look at and understand.

|Common Name | Genus/Phylum/Type| Total Pop.| Trend|

Answer (score 3):

4000 items (whether species or inventory) is not a lot. Your users are domain experts (or should be) and you ought to be able to allow users to filter / sort their way to find the item they're interested in.

Most people do not want to look through a list of 4000 items to find what they're looking for. Help them narrow the search.

Speak to your users if you don't have domain experience (and even if you do) to see how they mentally categorize the data (Location, eco-system, etc).

Comment: In terms of sorting and filtering I was thinking to segregate information according to genus/phyla, trend, and population as per user input or just display all. All the information presented to the user would be specific to a geographical location. I guess what I am confused on is why 4,000 or more records displayed on a single page would be considered okay from a user experience point of view?

Comment: @Sibi. 4000 on one page is a lot. You'll have to use pagination (do you consider that to be one page?) or lazy-loading. Try to help them narrow the search results.

Comment: I am open to any ideas really, I'm just not sure how to represent the data that I have available. What would be better, using something like JScroll for lazy loading or a pagination mechanism where the user clicks a button and it moves to another section of the data?

Comment: @Sibi - are you certain that there is a use case in which a user is looking for a particular record out of ALL 4000 records?  What percentage of queries result in < 10 queries,  > 50 queries. etc....

Comment: the user I believe should be able to compare species trend and observe a relationship that could correlate to population size/density etc. so they may need access to a one or more species of the habitat. I'm not sure if that answers your question...

Comment: also I was just wondering what you meant by "What percentage of queries result in < 10 queries, > 50 queries. etc.". Could you elaborate a little more on this for me?

Comment: @Sibi - A user is looking for a species; filters [North America] [Wetland] [ Endangered] and gets a result. How many results are expected?  Domain experts ought to be able to give you this data. If not. You'll have to test.

Comment: oh k i think i got it now, so I should see how the filters will affect the returns from their respective queries. Thanks @Mayo.

Answer (score 0):

4000 Records is not a report, it's a data dump. It's unreasonable to expect people to scroll 3999 records to get to the animal they want.

I would do filtering on Species > Genum

Comment: so what would be the difference between report and a data dump. Am I not showing them the information that the user wants to see?

Comment: @Sibi. no. A data dump is when someone wants to see all the data (for whatever reason). The user is not looking for ONE particular record.

Comment: Oh ok sorry I misunderstood what data dump implied. Is data dumping considered a bad thing from the user experience standpoint?

Comment: @Sibi. If he's looking for a particular item? Yes. Of course. Data dump is a generic term for simply vomiting data without paying any attention to what comes out. "Here it is."  Is there a use case for it? Sure - it's just like looking at raw server logs.